# Choice of contour for evaluating real integral using Cauchy Residue Theorem

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

If we have a function $f(x)$ for which we would like to evaluate the integral

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) dx$$

We could apply the Cauchy Residue Theorem pick a contour C, that contains the real axis part of the original integral. $[0,\infty]$ and then argue

$$\int_{\gamma} f(z) dz = 2\pi i * \sum{Res(f(z); b)}$$

where b are the poles of $f(z)$ contained inside $\gamma$. And then in addition show by Estimation that the parts of the contour that do not lie on the Real Axis tend toward 0.

Since we can choose our contour C, can we not just pick a $\gamma(t)$ as an incredibly small slice of the unit circle that contains no singularities of $f(z)$. Then argue, since none of the poles are contained within $\gamma$, the integral evaluates to 0?

For example, we could define 
$$f(z) = \frac{1}{(z^2+4)(z^2+9)}$$
We have simple poles at $2i,-2i,3i,-3i$. All these poles lie on the imaginary axis, so we define $\gamma$ to be the pie slice of the unit circle with radius $R \rightarrow \infty$ and angle of $\pi/4$

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(z^2+4)(z^2+9)} + \int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{1}{(\gamma_1(t)^2+4)(\gamma_1(t)^2+9)} \frac{d\gamma_1}{dt} dt - \int_{0}^{Re^{\pi/4}}\frac{1}{(\gamma_2(t)^2+4)(\gamma_2(t)^2+9)} \frac{d\gamma_2}{dt} dt = 2\pi i * \sum{Res(f(z); b)}
$$

where $\gamma_1(t) = Re^{it}$, $\gamma_2(t) = Re^{i\pi /4} t$

Since none of poles are inside, this integral is 0. But this isn't correct, its supposed to be

$$\frac{\pi}{2(4)(9)(9+4)}$$

The textbook I'm using says to pick $\gamma$ to be the semi circle which happens to only include poles in the upper half of the complex plane, but does not include poles in the lower half. A semi circle also doesn't work in this case since its $[0,\infty]$ and not $[-\infty,\infty]$ But anyways, **how come we can choose $\gamma$ to be the closed semi circle and exclude poles in the lower half plane, while we can't choose $\gamma$ to just exclude all poles and say it's 0. Is there a requirement that we must have at least 1 pole inside our contour?**

Comment: You will have to see what happens to the integral over $\gamma_2$ when you let $R \to \infty$. Without that you cannot evaluate $\int_0^{\infty} \frac  1 {(x^{2}+4)(x^{2}+9) } dx$.

Comment: @KaboMurphy Wouldn't that by the Estimation Lemma yield 0, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma since we would a $R^4$ term in the denominator and a $R$ in the numerator?

Comment: No the limit is not zero.  It is this limit which gives you the value of the original integral. Note that inetegral over $\gamma_2$ involes values of $f(z)$ for $z$ close to the origin also.

Comment: The integral over the closed contour would be $0$, but don’t forget that there are three arcs contributing to the contour. You have the be able to tell what happens on the other arcs to calculate the arc lying on the real axis.

Comment: I think my whole confusion with this question was because $\gamma_2$ is not the correct function. It should be $\gamma_2 = e^{i\pi/4}t $ (no factor of R) That would explain why I thought the integral that went to 0 by the estimation lemma instead of some other value. Where t ranges from 0 to R